# Google Visualization group() aggregation function returning nulls

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I have a column called `someNumber` which contains nulls and zeros.  When applying `google.visualization.data.group` to this column I cannot get the zero to come through to the table, only the null.

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#data_aggregation_functions) for both `.min` and `.max` indicates nulls are ignored but I can't seem to return anything but the null.

How can I get the zero to come through to my table?

Thank you experts!

Working Example:

```js
// Load the Visualization API and the corechart package.
google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages': ['corechart', 'table', 'gauge', 'controls']
});

// Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(gChart0);

function gChart0() {
  drawChart();
};

function drawChart() {

  var result = [{
    "calendarWeek": "2017-W30",
    "clnCount": 1,
    "someNumber": null //NOTE THIS IS SET TO NULL
  }, {
    "calendarWeek": "2017-W30",
    "clnCount": 3,
    "someNumber": 0 //NOTE THIS IS SET TO ZERO
  }];

  //Create DataTable
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Calendar Week');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Count');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Some Number');
  
  var dataArray = [];
  $.each(result, function(i, obj) {
    dataArray.push([
      obj.calendarWeek,
      obj.clnCount,
      obj.someNumber
    ]);
  });
  data.addRows(dataArray);

  //grouping 
  var groupView = google.visualization.data.group(data,
    [{
      column: 0,
      type: 'string'
    }],
    [{
        column: 1,
        aggregation: google.visualization.data.sum,
        type: 'number'
      },
      {
        column: 2,
        aggregation: google.visualization.data.min,
        type: 'number'
      }
    ]);

  //Options
  var options = {};

  // Instantiate and draw chart, passing in options.
  var chart = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(groupView, options);

} //END  function drawChart()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can provide your own custom aggregation functions.
the aggregation function should accept an array of values as the only argument.

in the custom sum function, we replace `null` with zero

```
function customSum(values) {
  var sum = 0;
  values.forEach(function (value) {
    sum += value || 0;
  });
  return sum;
}
```

in the custom min function, `Math.min` will return zero when both values are `null`

```
function customMin(values) {
  var min = null;
  values.forEach(function (value) {
    min = Math.min(value, min);
  });
  return min;
}
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages': ['corechart', 'table', 'gauge', 'controls']
});

// Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(gChart0);

function gChart0() {
  drawChart();
};

function drawChart() {

  var result = [{
    "calendarWeek": "2017-W30",
    "clnCount": 1,
    "someNumber": null //NOTE THIS IS SET TO NULL
  }, {
    "calendarWeek": "2017-W30",
    "clnCount": 3,
    "someNumber": 0 //NOTE THIS IS SET TO ZERO
  }];

  //Create DataTable
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Calendar Week');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Count');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Some Number');

  var dataArray = [];
  $.each(result, function(i, obj) {
    dataArray.push([
      obj.calendarWeek,
      obj.clnCount,
      obj.someNumber
    ]);
  });
  data.addRows(dataArray);

  //grouping
  var groupView = google.visualization.data.group(data,
    [{
      column: 0,
      type: 'string'
    }],
    [{
        column: 1,
        aggregation: customSum,
        type: 'number'
      },
      {
        column: 2,
        aggregation: customMin,
        type: 'number'
      }
    ]);

  function customSum(values) {
    var sum = 0;
    values.forEach(function (value) {
      sum += value || 0;
    });
    return sum;
  }

  function customMin(values) {
    var min = null;
    values.forEach(function (value) {
      min = Math.min(value, min);
    });
    return min;
  }

  //Options
  var options = {};

  // Instantiate and draw chart, passing in options.
  var chart = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(groupView, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: It's odd that Google didn't do this already in their aggregation API.  I've implemented your suggestion into my application.  I added to your snippet the jQuery reference to make the $.each work.  Thank you once again, have a good day!

Comment: thanks, I was wondering why it wasn't working. it usually gives an error, but it didn't do anything. I thought it was just taking a while, I'm not all that patient...

Answer (score 0):

Tested a max version and it also works.  Here's the code to share:

```
function customMax(values) {
    var max = null;
    values.forEach(function (value) {
        max = Math.max(value, max);
    });
    return max;
}
```